# How to customize annotation's layout in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, annotations

I have been using HighCharts extensively for one of my project. Recently I started using Annotation.js along with it.

ALthough, the library works well but I can't configure its usage at all. The [link](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations) here provides options but they are not working for me

My issues:

1. I have multiple charts on a page. As soon as I use annotation.js , each of them shows annotation. how do I show them on desired charts. I tried 
   `annotations :[{ enabledButtons : false}]`
   and 
   `annotationOptions :{ enabledButtons : false}`

Both of them had no affect.

2.I want to display the pallette (containing icons like square, circle etc..) at top-right. 
I used `xValue, yValue` attribute,
I used `x, y` attribute,
I used 'anchorX and anchorY` attribute.

None of the above works for me.

3. I want just to show the text icon. How can I hide other icons (line, square and circle). Didn't get any way to try for this one.

Am I missing something here. Kindly suggest. My basic way of using chart config is as below:

```
chart: {
                    type: chartData.Type.toLowerCase()
                    //annotations: [],

                },
                annotationsOptions: {
                    xValue: 234,
                    yValue:12
                },
                title: {
                    text: chartData.xTitle ? chartData.xTitle : ""
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: chartData.Categories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: chartData.yTitle ? chartData.yTitle : ""
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: "#808080"
                    }]
                },
                 annotations: [{
                    xValue: 40,
                    yValue: 15
                }],
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: chartData['Series'][opt] ? chartData['Series'][opt] : chartData['Series'][opt.replace(/-|\s/g, "")],
            }
```

I have tried annotations inside charts object as well.

Comment: So you would like to get something similar to this charts? http://jsfiddle.net/7m3Mr/261/

Comment: Here you can find an example how you can move your buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/7m3Mr/263/ If you want something else, please post more specific information what you would like to achieve, like drawing.

Comment: Well, two things are solved, first now I get only `T` icon. Second I am able to locate my button at right top. But why do I need to keep the `annotationEvents` object. This was not present in default implementation at site

Comment: It is because right now you are adding custom buttons. If you think it would be good idea to have it better explained on annotations site or to have a possibility to add buttons easier way, you may post it on github: https://github.com/blacklabel/annotations/issues Do you have more questions connected with this problem? If not, I would like to post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to hide annotations buttons using:

```
annotationsOptions: {
  enabledButtons: false
},
```

You can use annotationsOptions.buttons for changing the buttons you would like to display. Here you can see the code that will show only text butotn:

```
annotationsOptions: {
  buttons: [{
    annotationEvents: {
      step: function() {}, // to be called during mouse drag for new annotation
      stop: function(e) {
          var ann = this,
            chart = ann.chart,
            index = chart.annotationInputIndex = chart.annotationInputIndex ? chart.annotationInputIndex : 1,
            input = document.createElement('span'),
            button;

          input.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="annotation-' + index + '" placeholder="Add text"><button class=""> Done </button>';
          input.style.position = 'absolute';
          input.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
          input.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';

          document.body.appendChild(input);
          input.querySelectorAll('input')[0].focus();
          button = input.querySelectorAll('button')[0];
          button.onclick = function() {
            var parent = this.parentNode;

            ann.update({
              title: {
                text: parent.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value
              }
            });
            parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
          };
          chart.annotationInputIndex++;
        } // to be called after mouse up / release
    },
    annotation: { // standard annotation options, used for new annotation
      anchorX: 'left',
      anchorY: 'top',
      xAxis: 0,
      yAxis: 0,
      shape: {
        // type: 'text'
      }
    },
    symbol: { // button symbol options
      shape: 'text', // shape, taken from Highcharts.symbols
      size: 12,
      style: {
        'stroke-width': 2,
        'stroke': 'black',
        fill: 'red',
        zIndex: 121
      }
    },
    style: { // buton style itself
      fill: 'black',
      stroke: 'blue',
      strokeWidth: 2,
    },
    size: 12, // buton size
    states: { // states for button 
      selected: {
        fill: '#9BD'
      },
      hover: {
        fill: '#9BD'
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Here you can find an example how it may work: http://jsfiddle.net/7m3Mr/261/

You can move your buttons using:

```
annotationsOptions: {
  buttonsOffsets: [0, -50],
},
```

Here you can find demo showing how it may work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7m3Mr/263/